# Org.Apache.Axis set HTTPHeader

Tags: java, soap, axis

At the moment I facing the Problem that i need to add an custom HTTP Header to an `org.apache.axis.client.Call`. But all I can find on how to do this is something like adding SOAP Headers, but this isn't what i was looking for.

Adding a simple `SOAPHeader` would be easy:

```
SOAPHeaderElement header = new SOAPHeaderElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("SessionID"), sessionId);
        _call.addHeader(header);
```

But can i do something simiular for `HTTPHeaders`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been explained on following url:
http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WebServicesHowTo

```
MessageContext msgContext = _call.getMessageContext();
MimeHeaders hd = msgContext.getMessage().getMimeHeaders();
hd.addHeader("SessionID", sessionId);
```

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that i don't have an SOAPMessage so I can't use this one. Do you have other solutions where there can be only a org.apache.axis.client.Stub would be used?

Comment: I see, then try to look into the handlers?   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html

Comment: I found another way to do this according to your link above. I will edit your answer :)

Comment: Thanks it helped me to get the privilege for commenting anywhere :)

Answer (score 6):

I generate my client using the wizard of eclipse, so I solved my problem extended the method on my service locator

```
@Override
public Call createCall() throws ServiceException {
    _call = new org.apache.axis.client.Call(this) {

        @Override
        public void setRequestMessage(Message msg) {
            super.setRequestMessage(msg);

            MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = msg.getMimeHeaders();
            mimeHeaders.addHeader("SessionID", SessionID);


        }

    };

    return _call;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to  add. This worked for me:

```
((Stub) service)._setProperty(Call.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, new Boolean(true));
((Stub) service)._setProperty(HTTPConstants.HEADER_COOKIE, "AuthToken=abc123");
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the only solution that actually worked for me.